# obj sequence to alembic format

Tags: objects, alembic

Hello I'm quite new in blender.

I've been working on converting obj sequence to alembic format by using blender.

I've used 'Stop Motion Add-on' and 'obj sequence as shape keys' , but it seems like it's not helpful to export objs as abc format.

I have different obj files per frame. And unfortunately each has different number of vertice. Because of this reason, I guess those add-ons are not suitable on what I am doing.

Any suggestions ???

I've just tried 'ShrinkWarp Modifier' to make the objs as shape keys. It works however I am not satisfied with the mesh made from this modifier...

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do something similar. This video might help you. https://youtu.be/Kx4IU8lUCDs?list=PLxQxoABIf8KYi8c_gVqUGSfIUyxX-NrKf

Basically, put a displace modifier with 0 influence on the object you want to export to trick blender into exporting it as an alembic cache properly.

Let me know if you found a different way to do this. I'm still experimenting and trying to find a good workflow.

Comment: Can confirm that this works with the stop motion obj addon. Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: In Blender 2.80, this workaround no longer works with a Displace modifier. Try using an Array Modifier with a "Count" of 1. That worked for me. It didn't preserve textures, though.

Answer (score 0):

(didn't test it with textures, they might get lost):

1. Download Blender 2.83.8 and install the addon "Stop Motion OBJ 2.1.0"
2. Import your obj sequnce: File -> import -> Mesh Sequence (under settings: "file name" must match your obj sequence name)
3. Add an Array modifer (Count:1)
4. Export as Alembic (.abc)

now you should have the animation stored in a single alembic file.

Answer (score -1):

I made a video tutorial how to make it without any plugin https://youtu.be/KRxDyloJRYU

-1 because of someone who don't like youtube, in the comment below. But don't afraid. It's working.

Comment: Please consider [expanding this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/280707/edit) to be a complete answer with the details here. If for some reason the video goes away, then there is nothing for future visitors to see. [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/387343) may be removed if not further improved.